# Setting exact margins

Tags: margins

I am writing a document for which I need the margin to be exactly as follows: left, right, top and bottom text margin all equal to 1in, distance from bottom of the paper to page number equal to 0.75in (I don't have any footnote or header to set).

I tried to use the `fullpage` package in LaTeX but it does not give me the 0.75in to the page number. Is there a way to force that? I tried to set manually the margins for a 8.5x11 paper but I am not succeeding.

---

I tried but after writing:

```
\documentclass[PhD]{class_file}
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
```

I get the error message `\paperwidth (0.0pt) too short`.

I don't see the `\paperwidth` is set to 0.0pt anywhere though..

Also it seems to me that depending on which machine I use to compile my `tex` file, I get different margins, even when I set them up manually (without using geometry). Is it possible?

---

Using the geometry package things seem to work a bit better now (I changed machine and the problem with the paper width previously mentioned disappeared).

```
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
```

gives me without problem upper, right and left margin of 1in. But the lower margin is 1.2in and I can't change it to be 1in even by using `bottom=1in` or `bottom=0.8in`. I really don't see how this can happen. Maybe a problem with the spacing between lines? The class files I am using can be fund at http://www.math.ucla.edu/help/tex/uclathes/

I erased the margin settings of `uclath12.clo` as the margin I need are different from the ones that this file gives. Thank you.

Comment: You should try the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). For example `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` provides a left/right/top/bottom margin of 1in.

Comment: Please provide `class_file.cls` if you're allowed.

Comment: @David I realize this is a fairly old post but I'm facing the exact same problem.  Would you mind sharing the `uclath12.clo` that you changed  (or the way you changed it)  so I don't have to figure it out all myself?  Much appreciated!

Comment: Please note that you should not mix usepackage fullpage with usepackage geometry. Using fullpage will force the margins.

Answer (score 132):

You can use `geometry` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=0.2in,
            left=1in,
            right=1in,
            top=1in,
            bottom=1in,
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

%================================

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

% In the middle if you want to change the margins use
\newgeometry{left=0.8in,right=0.8in,top=1in,bottom=1in}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

%to restore old margins, use
\restoregeometry

\blindtext

%===============================

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the `\newgeoemtry` macro, I was looking for that!

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that, in your TeX file, there is no indication of paper size. So you can add the *a4paper* option for instance to your geometry package option list like this:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
```

or you can specify it in your document class options.

Comment: If anyone has this issue with a custom, university-provided document class, one can reasonably question what they were thinking when designing the document class without providing a somewhat more reasonable default paper width...

Answer (score 18):

Expanding on Werner's comment, to get the page number's baseline 0.75 in above the page's bottom edge, use `footskip`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

With geometry package:

```
\usepackage[nohead, nomarginpar, margin=1in, foot=.25in]{geometry}
```

Or without a package:

```
\pdfpagewidth 8.5in
\pdfpageheight 11in
\headheight 0pt
\headsep 0pt
\footskip .25in
\marginparwidth 0pt
\marginparsep 0pt
\oddsidemargin \dimexpr 1in -1in
\topmargin \dimexpr 1in -1in
\textwidth \dimexpr \pdfpagewidth -2\oddsidemargin -2in
\textheight \dimexpr \pdfpageheight -2\topmargin -2in
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to do margins by hand, `geometry` does a fine job.

Comment: Also, that is not the way you set lengths in LaTeX, but plain.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is the most efficient way but this worked for me

```
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{710pt}
```

In short
`\voffset` is the distance from top of the page to the bottom of header portion
`\textheight` is the total height of main text.

See [this page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins#Paper_size.2C_orientation_and_margins) for full understanding of above variables.

Comment: `\voffset` should be reserved for special printing purposes, such as cropping.