# How can I change the margins in LaTeX?

Tags: margins, geometry

How do I change the margin of all pages?

I want the latex page be .25 in margin around all the pages.

Comment: Maybe one should add for clarification that from a typographical point of view it considered bad style to just set all margins to an identical fixed value. In typography the page margins are at a specific geometric relation compared to for example the page aspect ratio and other things. For some more explanation compare for example the [KOMA Script Guide](http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), Section " Fundamentals of Page Layout".

Comment: [Welcome to TX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Your question is probably already answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46175/21591).

Comment: You may look into here for more info https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Page_size_and_margins

Comment: The wikibooks page is quite good https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Adding this to the header of your document will set a 0.25in margin for every side of the page:

```
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
```

A good website for reference is:
http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907057