# Set fixed bottom margin size in a custom class

Tags: margins, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to modify a custom thesis-setting class to my needs. It contains commands for setting odd, even and top margins, but **I need a particular size (25mm) of the bottom margin** as well. I did expect it to be the most elementary feature of LaTeX, but commands such as `\bottom` or `\bmargin` lead to crashes of my document. Research on the internet showed, that the bottom margin is not even there on the command-explaining diagram (example: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Page_size_and_margins).

So **my question** is: How do I set a fixed bottom margin size within a class?

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also, have you tried the `geometry` package?

Comment: In addition to the MWE already requested, could you provide a link or the source of the custom thesis-setting class?

Comment: In any case, the bottom and right margins are just whatever is left of \paperheight and \paperwidth after everything else is specified.

Comment: User haven't been active since the question was posted, not enough info to properly answer. Vote to close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting exact margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46175/setting-exact-margins)