# Can margins be set in compile command?

Tags: margins

To conserve screen space while editing it would be nice to compile without margins when still working on a paper. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: You can probably set the margins with the `geometry` package (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46175), and remove that setting when you're done.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Can you please post that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I asked a different question but wanted the same but learned from the reply that I was trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: We might as well close as duplicate then, if that's OK with you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do different as Torbjørn T. suggested above. In fact, I have done this often enough for printing other's papers to increase the font size.

The `pdfcrop` executable removes all the margin. You only need to take care for page numbering and other elements in the margins, but you can turn that off in your preamble.

I suspect, the result will look ugly, but `--margin` option to `pdfcrop` might help a but. You might want to go as far as developing a whole new "web" version. Someone I know kept the margin and all the formatting, but turned the `twopage` option off.

Comment: Well, is this faster to compile first and then use another executable to remove the margins after?

Comment: Nope, it ain't. But the question was about cropping margins, which my suggestion does.