# Feynman Diagram Drawing

Tags: feynman, axodraw4j

So I'm using Jaxodraw to make Feynman Diagrams. The code I exported from Jaxodraw is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{axodraw4j}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-2in}

\pagestyle{empty}



\begin{document}

%%JaxoComment:
%%JaxoScale{1.0}


\begin{center}
\fcolorbox{white}{white}{
  \begin{picture}(596,144) (110,-139)
    \SetWidth{1.0}
    \SetColor{Black}
    \COval(160,-80)(32,32)(0){Black}{White}
    \COval(352,-80)(32,32)(0){Black}{White}
    \COval(528,-80)(32,32)(0){Black}{White}
    \COval(656,-80)(32,32)(0){Black}{White}
    %
    % There is a postscript text here!
    % There is a postscript text here!
    \SetWidth{1.5}
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=8.833,arrowwidth=3.533,arrowinset=0.2](184,-57)(208,-32)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=8.833,arrowwidth=3.533,arrowinset=0.2](182,-104)(208,-128)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=8.833,arrowwidth=3.533,arrowinset=0.2](112,-128)(138,-104)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=10.5,arrowwidth=4.2,arrowinset=0.2](112,-32)(137,-57)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=10.5,arrowwidth=4.2,arrowinset=0.2](376,-57)(400,-32)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=9,arrowwidth=3.6,arrowinset=0.2](375,-103)(400,-128)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=9,arrowwidth=3.6,arrowinset=0.2](304,-128)(331,-104)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=9,arrowwidth=3.6,arrowinset=0.2](304,-32)(329,-58)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=10.5,arrowwidth=4.2,arrowinset=0.2](480,-32)(504,-57)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=9,arrowwidth=3.6,arrowinset=0.2](480,-128)(505,-103)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=10.5,arrowwidth=4.2,arrowinset=0.2](679,-57)(704,-32)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=9,arrowwidth=3.6,arrowinset=0.2](679,-103)(704,-128)
    \Arc[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=10,arrowwidth=4,arrowinset=0.2,clock](592,-78.12)(46.12,152.746,27.254)
    \Arc[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=9,arrowwidth=3.6,arrowinset=0.2](592,-81.88)(46.12,-152.746,-27.254)
    \Text(112,-144)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$p_2$}}}
    \Text(208,-144)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$p_4$}}}
    \Text(112,-16)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$p_1$}}}
    \Text(208,-32)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$p_3$}}}
  \end{picture}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The only thing showing up when I run that is the different p's. Anyone have any suggestions for how to get the diagram to show up?

Answer (score 1):

You probably generated the PDF with `pdflatex`. For the diagrams to work, I believe you have to use `latex` followed by `dvips` followed by `ps2pdf`. Exactly how you do that depends on your editor, if you use the command line to compile the document you need to do

```
latex filename.tex
dvips filename.dvi
ps2pdf filename.ps
```

The resulting PDF should then contain the diagram, looking like this:

[image]

A few things to note:

- The diagram is too wide for the page, so you should reduce the size a bit. (I don't know Jaxodraw, so can't say how.)
- The reason `p_2` and `p_4` look a bit weird, is that they're covered by the `\fcolorbox`, so I'd remove that.
- `\Large` doesn't take an argument, it should be used as `{\Large text}`, not `\Large{text}`.
- In general, instead of manually setting all the different margins, `\textwidth` etc., use the `geometry` package. See [Setting exact margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46175/setting-exact-margins/46178#46178) for an example.

If you want to avoid going via DVI and PostScript to get a PDF, you should look at other packages for generating your diagrams, such as `tikz`, or `tikz-feynman`.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question, but just doing what Torbjørn T. is suggesting: redrawing the thing with tikz-feynman. Well, almost, I could really not draw a diagram with vertices at which three fermion lines meet, so I replaces some of the straight lines by gluons. Notice also that you do *not* need to compile the thing with lualatex. Even though I highly respect the work done by Joshua Ellis on the automatic placement, I found that in practice it does often not lead to a very nice output when the diagram becomes more complicated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.0.0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={[inset=0,length=8,angle'=30,bend]Stealth}, line width=.7pt]
\begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[below right= 1.12 cm of a1](a2);
            \vertex[below=4cm of a1] (b1);
            \vertex[right= 2.12 cm of a2](a3);
            \vertex[below= 2.12 cm of a2](a4);
            \vertex[above right = 1.12 cm of a3] (a7);
            \vertex[below right=3cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[below right = 1.12 cm of a5] (b2);
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [gluon,momentum'={[arrow style=blue]\(p_1\)}] (a2)
                -- [fermion, quarter left] (a3)
                -- [fermion, quarter left] (a5)
                -- [fermion, quarter left] (a4)
                -- [fermion, quarter left] (a2),
                (b1) -- [gluon,momentum'={[arrow style=blue]\(p_2\)}] (a4),
                (a3) -- [gluon,momentum'={[arrow style=blue]\(p_3\)}] (a7),        
                (a5) -- [gluon,momentum'={[arrow style=blue]\(p_4\)}] (b2)        
            };
\end{feynman}
\begin{feynman}[xshift=5cm]
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[below right= 1.12 cm of a1](a2);
            \vertex[below=4cm of a1] (b1);
            \vertex[right= 2.12 cm of a2](a3);
            \vertex[below= 2.12 cm of a2](a4);
            \vertex[below right=3cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=2cm of a5] (a6); 
            \vertex[right=3cm of a3] (r3);
            \vertex[right=3cm of a5] (r5);
            \vertex[right=2cm of r3] (r2);
            \vertex[right=2cm of r5] (r4);
            \vertex[above right= 1.12 cm of r2](f1);
            \vertex[below right= 1.12 cm of r4](f2);
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [gluon,momentum'={[arrow style=blue]\(p_1\)}] (a2)
                -- [fermion, quarter left] (a3)
                -- [fermion, quarter left] (a5)
                -- [fermion, quarter left] (a4)
                -- [fermion, quarter left] (a2),
                (b1) -- [gluon,momentum'={[arrow style=blue]\(p_2\)}] (a4),
                 (a3) -- [gluon,quarter left] (r3),        
                 (a5) -- [gluon,quarter right] (r5)
                 -- [fermion, quarter left] (r3)
                -- [fermion, quarter left] (r2)
                -- [fermion, quarter left] (r4)
                -- [fermion, quarter left] (r5),
                (r2) -- [gluon,momentum'={[arrow style=blue]\(p_3\)}] (f1),        
                (r4) -- [gluon,momentum'={[arrow style=blue]\(p_4\)}] (f2)        
            };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you to have a look to this interesting documentation: http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/graphics/axodraw/axodraw.pdf

Second, you can also test my LaTeX code.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{axodraw4j}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{tikz} % I use it to place a grid with tikz grid command
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}\begin{picture}(300,56)(0,0)
    \Vertex(180,10){1.5}
    \Vertex(120,10){1.5}
    \SetColor{Red}
    \ArrowLine(100,10)(200,10)
    \SetColor{Green}
    \LongArrowArc(150,10)(20,60,120)
    \SetColor{Brown}
    \PhotonArc(150,10)(30,0,180){4}{8.5}   % 8.5 wiggles
    \end{picture}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \fcolorbox{white}{white}{
    \begin{picture}(596,144) (110,-139)
    \SetWidth{1.0}
    \SetColor{Black}
    \Gluon(100,-200)(200,0){50}{8}   
    \end{picture}
    }

   \begin{picture}(162,39) (0,0)
   \Line[arrow,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2](0,19)(48,19)
   \Arc[arrow,arrowlength=5,arrowwidth=2](80,43)(40,-143.13,-36.87)
   \Line(112,19)(160,19)
   \GluonArc(80,-5)(40,37,143){3.5}{6}
   \Text(112,-16)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$p_1$}}}
   \Text(208,-32)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$p_3$}}}
   \tikz{\draw[step=1.0,black,thin] (0.5,0.5) grid (5.5,4.5);}
   \end{picture}%
   \end{center}

   \end{document}
```

I suggest you to edit manually your LaTeX code because the origin of the trouble seem to be the Jaxodraw software, but not LaTeX itself.