# twoside report text shifting

Tags: double-sided, report

I'm using \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report} and because of "twoside" the first page is shifted to the left, the second page to the right, the third to the left and so on. Shouldn't it be shifted the other way, to get more distance between the text and the back of the book? Is it possible to turn the shifting the other way around?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42063/illogical-twoside-margins You can change margins as you want with the `geometry` package. Edit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46175/setting-exact-margins/46178#46178

Comment: no the margins on the outer edges are traditionally wider, for your thumbs, and because the two inner margins already add up to a lot of white space.